# Why use a List over a HashSet?

Tags: c#, list, hashset

May be an obvious question, but I've seen plenty of reasons why to use a HashSet over a list/array.
I've heard it has O(1) for removing and searching for data.

I've never heard why to use a list over a HashSet.

So why vice-versa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- A list allows duplicates, a `HashSet` does not
- List is ordered by it's index, a `HashSet` has no implicit order
- Performance is often overrated, choose the right tool for the job

Comment: [How mony times do I have tae tell ye, use th' right tool fur the right job!](http://076dd0a50e0c1255009e-bd4b8aabaca29897bc751dfaf75b290c.r40.cf1.rackcdn.com/images/files/000/412/152/original/original.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

They have different semantics. A list is ordered (by insert order), allows duplicates, and offers random-access by index; a hash-set is unordered, does not allow duplicates (removes them, by design), and does not offer random-access. Both are perfectly valid, simply: for different scenarios.

Comment: @Joey exactly how? what API would allow for that? all it offers is "add", "remove", "contains". You'd actually need to be **holding** the thing you are looking for.

Comment: @Joey Only for the `Contains`. Sadly you can't overload the equality/gethash methods and get the item in the list by using a "similar" item.

Comment: @Joey is it possible that you're thinking of `Hashtable`? That is not the same API as `HashSet<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Well for one, you can insert duplicates into a List/Array.

From [HashSet.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx)

> Return Value Type:
>
> System.Boolean
>
> true if the element is added to the HashSet object;
>
> false if the element is already present.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to the party, but I want to add something to the chosen answer by turning the question on its head:

**When to use HashSet over List?**

1. When your objects in the Set will certainly be unique or you want to never add duplicates.
2. You often want to look up if certain objects are in the Set.
3. If you often *remove* objects. Adding takes about the same time as adding objects into a List, but removing them is much, much faster in a HashSet.
4. If you don't care about about order or direct access via an index.

Keep in mind, you can "foreach" through a HashSet as well.

Rango is right that performance is sometimes overvalued; but *if* performance is critical (and order unimportant), HashSets can by magnitudes be faster than Lists.